# URL for a file stored in app_data folder in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

How to give URL in view for a file stored in app_data folder in mvc

```
 <a href="/APP_Data/filename.csv"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double-dot ("..") directory notation can be used anywhere in a directory name to represent going up one level.
For example; if your project folder is in desktop (C:\Users\sampleUser\Desktop\Project). In case that you should that:

```html
<a href="../../APP_Data/filename.csv"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```